# TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'show_accuracy': True} #yelp challenge dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano

> File
>   "/home/susheel/LearnPython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py",
>   line 848, in fit
>       raise TypeError('Unrecognized keyword arguments: ' + str(kwargs)) TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'show_accuracy': True}

While I am trying to find the sentiment on Yelp Data Academic.json using CNN in deep learning. I am getting the above error I treid its coming in numpy error but i didnt resolved can anyone help how can

Comment: Please provide the source code.

Comment: Yeah now show_accuracy has deprecated. Use metrics=['accuracy'] on model.compile()

Answer (score 7):

If you want to print the accuracy while training your model you do not need to specify it in `model.fit` but in the `model.compile`. Here you can set the `metrics=['accuracy']` argument.

**Example**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, verbose=1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In older versions of Keras (< 1) the argument `show_accuracy=True` does exist.

---

**EDIT 2:**

With tensorflow 2.0 keras is included. With this version you should use `metrics=['acc']`.